# Possibility for Fake NFC(Near Field Communication) Launch

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, nfc

I am working on **Near Field Communication** for reading data from NFC Tags.
I don't have **NFC supported Android Mobile and NFC Tags** to test the Application i created  .

I want to know whether it is possible to **Launch my App through intent filter**(Should assume  NFC tag is detected from my device)

My Manifest Snippet :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ServerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="abc.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/aaap"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My Activity Snippet :

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research on NFC i found that we can read/write NFC Tags without NFC enabled device.. But answer is so simple.. It's nothing but playing with Intents :

We have to call this snippet for invoking NFC :

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    intent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES, "Custom Messages");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Also we should register our Activity to Android System through Manifest file like below :

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <activity
        android:name="TagViewer" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Same way if you have more than one Activity using same action  we will be getting chooser from which we can launch our Desired Activity.

Receiving inside Activity :

**TagViewer .java**

```
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Log.v("NFC Launched","NFC Launched");           
    }
```

We have this sample in [Developer Sample Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I may be completely missing the point here, but from what I understood, you basically want to fire off an intent that will get picked by the receiver you declared in your manifest, right? Have you tried setting up a *very* simple test app that does exactly this using the `sendBroadcast(...)` method?

```
Intent exampleIntent = new Intent("android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED");
sendBroadcast(exampleIntent)
```

You can add any extra data to the `Intent` per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Open NFC. They have a [NFC simulator](http://open-nfc.org/wp/nfchal/simulator/) that migh be useful to attach to your android simulator. Never used it with Android, but I've used it with BlackBerry simulators.

EDIT:
[Last version 4.4.1 for Android ICS released.](http://open-nfc.org/wp/2012/04/12/open-nfc-4-4-1-for-android-ics-4-0-3/)

Comment: This solution doesn't exist anymore.