# Testing an app by faking NFC tag scan

Tags: android, android-intent, mocking, nfc, ndef

I am new to Android, working on Near Field Communication for reading data from NFC tags. Neither I have NFC supported Android mobile nor NFC tags to test the application I created.

I found the below two posts which says about faking NFC tag scans by triggering an Intent.

1. [Possibility for Fake NFC(Near Field Communication) Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346894/possibility-for-fake-nfcnear-field-communication-launch)
2. [Need To Fake an NFC Tag Being Scanned In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557548/need-to-fake-an-nfc-tag-being-scanned-in-android)

I changed my code according to the first post, where on click of a button I am triggering the required Intent in the 1st activity. Whereas I have created one more activity capable of handling that same intent. The reading of NFC tag and handling data is based on a button click on the 2nd activity.

The problem is: Whenever I am triggering the fake NFC tag scan intent from the 1st activity, it is throwing an error "**No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED (has extras) }**".

The Manifest file goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.expensemanager.saubhattacharya">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Set_Monthly_Target"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_set__monthly__target"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.expensemanager.saubhattacharya.MainActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Add_Daily_Expense"
        android:label="@string/add_daily_expense_activity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.expensemanager.saubhattacharya.MainActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The intent trigger code snippet from the 1st activity is below:

```
public void scan_tag (View view)
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    intent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES, "Custom Messages");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code snippet from the 2nd activity, which handles the above trigger is below:

```
public class Add_Daily_Expense extends AppCompatActivity {

Button read_data;
TextView show_data;
Tag detected_tag;
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
IntentFilter[] intentFilters;
public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
public static final String MIME_IMAGE_ALL = "image/*";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__daily__expense);
    final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    show_data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_data);
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    read_data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_nfc);
    read_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add_Daily_Expense.this);
                    builder.setMessage("NFC feature is not available on this device!")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NFC feature is available on this device!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                HandleIntent(getIntent());
            }
        }
    });
}

public void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action))
    {
        detected_tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(nfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        NDefReaderTask NDefReader = new NDefReaderTask();
        NDefReader.execute();
    }
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(nfcAdapter != null)
    setupForeGroundDispatch(this, nfcAdapter);
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if(nfcAdapter != null)
    stopForeGroundDispatch(this, nfcAdapter);
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    HandleIntent(intent);
}

public void setupForeGroundDispatch (final Activity activity, NfcAdapter nfcAdapter)
{
    Intent new_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Add_Daily_Expense.class);
    new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,new_intent,0);
    intentFilters = new IntentFilter[1];
    String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

    intentFilters[0] = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    try {
        intentFilters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
        intentFilters[0].addDataType(MIME_IMAGE_ALL);
    }
    catch(IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException me)
    {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }

    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, intentFilters, techList);
}

public void stopForeGroundDispatch (final Activity activity, NfcAdapter nfcAdapter)
{
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
}

public class NDefReaderTask extends AsyncTask <Tag, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Tag... params)
    {
        try
        {
            detected_tag = params[0];
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(detected_tag);
            ndef.connect();
            if(ndef != null)
            {
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();
                NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
                for(NdefRecord ndefRecord : records)
                {
                    if((ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_ABSOLUTE_URI) || (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN))
                    {
                        byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
                        String encoding1 = "UTF-8";
                        String encoding2 = "UTF-16";
                        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? encoding1 : encoding2;
                        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;
                        return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
                    }
                }
            }
            ndef.close();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException UE)
        {
            UE.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException IE)
        {
            IE.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if(result != null)
        {
            show_data.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My question is: What is wrong I am doing here? Is there any other way to test my app by faking the NFC tag scan?

Answer (score 2):

You specify a MIME type filter for the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent filter:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
```

Consequently, the fake NFC intent needs to contain one of these MIME types to match the intent filter. You can add the type information to the intent using the `setType()` method:

```
public void scan_tag (View view) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES, ...);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Also note that the above code won't add a tag handle to the NFC intent. Hence, you can't obtain a `Tag` object with

```
detected_tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(nfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

Consequently, you also can't obtain an instance of the `Ndef` connection class using

```
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(detected_tag);
```

You might want to look into the following questions/answers regarding mock tag objects:

- [How to mock a Android NFC Tag object for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30841803/2425802)
- [Is there a way to create an ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED intent from code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26712905/2425802)
- [How to simulate the tag touch from other application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28046115/2425802)

Finally, be aware that there are several other issues in your code.

Comment: @Michael--  Thanks a lot! I will go through the points mentioned by you and let you know the outcome. Yes, I assumed that there will be several in my code as I am new to this, that's why I want to do proper unit testing. :)

Comment: @Michael-- If possible, can you please tell me roughly which all the issues I have in my code? Or my approach in this case was wrong? I am trying to do some Unit Testing meanwhile.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by keeping MIME type only as Text. I was able to capture in the intent. But since I was not able to get the NFC Adapter and Tag information, I was not able to test the entire code.
Meanwhile, if it is possible please highlight what all the issues I have in the code?

Comment: @SaumikBhattacharya One problem is, for instance, that you set `detected_tag = params[0];` in your AsyncTask but that you never pass the tag handle as parameter to the task (instead you directly update `detected_tag` with it which you later overwrite with `params[0]` again). Another one is that you use `getIntent()` to obtain the tag handle in your HandleIntent method (instead of using the parameter `intent`).

Comment: How does this fake an NFC scan - like OP requested?